# Custom parameters for bootstrap-table server side pagination

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a service created with spring boot, for which I am trying to display its data using the [bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) library.

My service allows pagination with the query parameters `?page=x&size=y`, where `page` starts at 0.

The response for the query returns something that looks like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "catalogueOrders": [ .... ]
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 11,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

Where `_embedded.catalogueOrders` contains all the data, and `page` contains the totals.

I tried configuring my table as following:

```js
$('#orderTable').bootstrapTable({
    url: "http://localhost:8088/catalogueOrders?orderStatus=" + orderState,
    columns: [
        {
            field: 'orderId',
            title: 'Order ID'
        },
        {
            field: 'priority',
            title: 'Priority'
        }
    ],
    pagination: true,
    sidePagination: 'server',
    totalField: 'page.totalElements',
    pageSize: 5,
    pageList: [5, 10, 25],
    responseHandler: function(res) {
        console.log(res)
        return res["_embedded"]["catalogueOrders"]
    }
})
```

This is able to retrieve and display the data, however it returns all the results, clearly due to it not knowing how to apply the pagination. Total elements doesn't seem to be retrieved either, as the table displays `Showing 1 to 5 of undefined rows`. Also, if I replace the `responseHandler` with `dataField: '_embedded.catalogueOrders'`, it's no longer displaying the data.

How do I configure the query parameters needed for pagination?

And am I doing anything wrong when I try and configure `dataField` and `totalField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

Not sure what was wrong with the `dataField` and `totalField`, but it seems to not work with nested fields. To resolve this, I formatted the response into a new object inside `responseHandler`:

```js
dataField: 'data',
totalField: 'total',
responseHandler: function(res) {
    return {
        data: res["_embedded"]["catalogueOrders"],
        total: res["page"]["totalElements"]
    }
}
```

As for the query parameters, by default, bootstrap-table provides the parameters `limit` and `offset`. To customize that and convert to `size` and `page` like in my case, the `queryParams` function can be provided:

```js
queryParams: function(p) {
    return {
        page: Math.floor(p.offset / p.limit),
        size: p.limit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one, yes, it doesn’t work with nested fields. if you want to use nested fields, try on sass code (get the compiler, just search up on web, there’s plenty of posts on the web).
two, i’m not exactly sure what you’re talking about, but you can set up a css variable

```css
:root{
  /*assign variables*/
  —-color-1: red;
  —-color-2: blue;
}

/*apply variables

p {
  color: var(-—color-1):
}
```

you can find loads of info on this on the web.

Comment: How would CSS help in this situation?